# Hyperledger Fabric: CreateChannel Issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

After installing all  Prerequisites for hyperledger fabric I installed binary images and Samples by running the command:

```
curl -sSL http:bit.ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s
```

In Samples I have network samples:
"first-network" and
"test-network"

At first, I ran
`./byfn.sh up` for first-network.
This command ran successfully.

then I ran 
`./byfn.sh down`
This was also successful.

Then I ran 
`./network.sh up` for test-network.
Successfully executed.

But when I tried to add a new channel to the network using the command
`./network.sh createChannel -c Channel1`,
it gave error:

> Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7050: connect: connection refused"
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

Comment: check if your orderer container is running or not?

Comment: channel names must be lowercase - worth retesting with a new name.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734794/orderer-node-exits-within-few-seconds-after-execution-of-network-sh-up-command/60430836#60430836) question may help you.

Answer (score 0):

check the `docker ps` to check the running processes, if *orderer* is not available in the list, *up the network again* using `./network.sh` or you can use detach mode either `docker-compose up -d` then run the command for creating the channel.