# Orderer node exits within few seconds after execution of "network.sh up" command

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am learning hyperledger fabric from the authorized documentation and following the steps given [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

I followed following steps as per documentation to install and run sample applications.

1. Installed all prerequisites as per the documentation.
2. Cloned github respository from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.
3. Ran bootstrap.sh script as per commands mentioned in the `readme.md` file (without giving any specific version as command-line parameters thinking that it will install correct latest versions). This command downloaded all binaries in the `bin` folder.
4. Executed `sudo ./network.sh up` command under test-network folder. It showed that 2 peer nodes and 1 orderer node started.

However, when I tried to create channel using `./network.sh createChannel`, it gave me error as

> Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to localhost:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7050: connect: connection refused"
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========
>   Error !!! Create channel failed

So, when I checked the status of nodes using `docker ps -a`, it gave me following output.

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS                    NAMES
>
> 978968f8e11e        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute               0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
>
> **89914237b249        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           About a minute ago   Exited (2) About a minute ago                            orderer.example.com**
>
> 7e79abb2aefa        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute               0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
>
> 0fa38487cdf4        hello-world                         "/hello"            4 hours ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                                   brave_galileo

I also get following warning whenever I try to execute `network.sh` command -

> LOCAL_VERSION=1.4.4
>     Base Image0.4.18
>
> DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.4.4
>
> =================== WARNING ===================
>
> Local fabric binaries and docker images are  out of  sync. This may cause problems.
>
> ===============================================

I do not know where to check which binaries are applicable to which docker images.

I tried several ways to keep orderer node alive by doing everything from scratch, giving permissions to all the folder under fabric-samples, down-up sequence of network.sh, restarting the network.sh and few more that I can think of, but still I am not able to keep orderer node alive.

Also I noticed that the statement is mentioned in the documentation that
 ***Install the Hyperledger Fabric platform-specific binaries and config files for the version specified into the /bin and /config directories of fabric-samples***

However, I did not find any bin and config folder under the given github repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of trial and error attempts, I could finally make it work.

First of all, I reinstalled the fabric-sample project using following command and made sure that I have correct binaries and docker images (rather than picking up everything latest) -

```
# Fetch bootstrap.sh from fabric repository using
curl -sS https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh -o ./scripts/bootstrap.sh
# Change file mode to executable
chmod +x ./scripts/bootstrap.sh
# Download binaries and docker images - **check out the version below**
./scripts/bootstrap.sh 1.4.4 -s
```

With this, I could get rid of warnings that I was getting related to out of sync local fabric binaries and docker images.

After that, I tried following troubleshooting steps which led me to the problem area -

1. I performed all the above `./network.sh` commands but failed to keep orderer node alive.
2. I decided to execute each network.sh command manually on command-prompt as it comes in the script sequentially. With this, I saw that there is no issue with `checkPrereqs` and `createOrgs` functions. `CreateOrgs` function becomes successful both ways - using cryptogen tool and using CA.
3. I commented out `createConsortium` function and executed `./network.sh up` command which kept orderer node alive.
4. Found out that `createConsortium` tries to generate genesis block under **system-genesis-block** folder and because of some reason, rather than generating file with the name **genesis-block**, there was the read-only folder named **genesis-block** due to which `configtxgen` command was failing.

Thus, I removed read-only permissions from this block and deleted the **genesis-block** folder and re-run `./network.sh down` and `./network.sh up` command after un-commenting `createConsortium` function, which resulted in the generation of a genesis block *file* rather than *folder* and thus, finally, I could manage to keep orderer node alive.

After this, I could successfully create channel using following command.

```
./network.sh createChannel
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the best answer, I managed to get `./network.sh createChannel` script working by **changing permissions of the genesis block file**:

```sh
chmod 664 system-genesis-block/genesis.block
```

Comment: Hi! I had the same problem with the creation of a channel. I am trying to execute the test network. The system-genesis-block folder is empty ?? what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have specified incorrect path for the genesis block. can you post your orderer logs?

Comment: Problem is already solved. There were permission issues with genesis block file. Check the answer above.

Comment: You are not supposed to put this as an answer. It should be a comment, when you are just asking for some extra information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get ./network.sh createChannel script working by changing permissions of the genesis block file. chmod 777 didn't work for me.

```
chmod 777 genesis.block
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify the fabric-peer and fabric-order version of dokcer images in file `docker-compose.yaml`, from latest to 2.3,and it is worked for me.

[image]